# PHPUnit - Creating tests after development

Tags: codeigniter, unit-testing, tdd, phpunit

I've watched and read a handful of tutorials on PHPUnit and Test Driven Development and have recently begun working with Laravel which extends the PHPUnit Framework with it's TestCase class.  All of these things make sense to me, as far as, creating tests as you develop.  And I find Laravel's extensions particularly intuitive (especially in regards to testing Controller routes)

However, I've recently been tasked with creating unit tests for a sizable app that's near completion.  The app is built in Codeigniter, and it was not built with any tests

I find that I'm not entirely sure where to begin, or what steps to take in order to determine the tests I should create.

Should I be looking to test each controller method? Or do I need to break it down more than that? Admittedly, many of these controller methods are doing more than one task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really difficult to write tests for existing project. I will suggest you to first start with writing tests for classes which are not dependent on other classes. Then you can continue to write tests to classes which coupled with classes for which you wrote tests. You will increase your test coverage step by step by repeating this process.

Also don't forget that some times you will need to refactor your code to make it testable. You should improve design of code for example if your controller methods doing more than one task you should divide this method to sub methods and test each of these methods independently.

I also will suggest you to look at this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/207401/writing-tests-for-existing-code)

Comment: Thanks, I figured it would be a tough thing.  I'm also looking into Acceptance Testing using Codeception.  I know it's minimal, but it may be the cheapest, framework-agnostic way of getting SOME testing in.  I'll also look into your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You are in a bit of a tight spot, but here is what I would do in your situation. You need to refactor (ie. change) the existing code so that you end up with three types of functions.

The first type are those that deal with the outside world. By this I mean anything that talks to I/O, or your framework or your operating system or even libraries or code from stable modules. Basically everything that has a dependency on code that you can not, or may not change.

The second group of functions are where you transform or create data structures. The only thing they should know about are the data structures that they receive as parameters and the only way they communicate back is by changing those structures or by creating and populating a new structure.

The third group consists of co-ordinating functions which make the calls to the outside world functions, get their returned data structures and pass those structures to the transforming functions.

Your testing strategy is then as follows: the second group can be tested by creating fake data structures, passing them in and checking that the transforms were done correctly. The third group of co-ordinating functions can be tested by dependency injection and mocking to see that they call the outside world and transform functions correctly. Finally the last group of functions should not be tested. You follow the maxim - "make it so simple that their is obviously nothing wrong". See if you can keep it to a single line of code. If you go over four lines of code for these then you are probably doing it wrong.

If you are completely new to TDD I do however strongly suggest that you first get used to doing it on green field projects/modules. I made a couple of false starts on unit testing because I tried to bolt it onto projects afterwards. TDD is really a joy when you finally grok it so it would not be good if you get discouraged early on because of a too steep learning curve.